# I want to remove duplicate entries separated by commas from text area when form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a text area and it takes numbers as data which are seperated by commas. I want to remove duplicate when form is submitted

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Oo I am going to remember that link @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought you knew of it (?)

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, but I do now, thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly *De rien* - [I found that here actually...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-commenting-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggesting-such-s#comment519574_357436).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$array = explode(",",$string)` then `array_unique($array);` and then `$string = implode(",",$array)`

```
<?php
    $string =  "10,12,10,15,12";// Textarea value
    $array = explode(",",$string);// make string to array separated by comma `,` 
    $array = array_unique($array); // remove duplicate from array
    $string = implode(",",$array); // again make array to string with comma `,` separated
    echo $string;
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/884529

Comment: this works but it sill is saving multiple entries in db?

Comment: Share your code which inserts text in db , I suggest to store single data in each row in separate table , for better performance

Answer (score 0):

If i assume that you are splitting the text on the "comma" that means its inside an array now. so use

```
$text = array("your comments seperated by comma");
$text = array_unique($text);
```